# How to make a mysql view for schedules of multiple people?

Tags: mysql, view

I have a table of data to describe a person's scheduled time.  It looks like this

```
Name | day | start_hour | end_hour
-
Tom | Monday   | 8  | 12
Tom | Weekend  | 16 | 20
Dick| Weekdays | 9  | 15
Sue | Sunday   | 7  | 23
```

How can I make a view that looks like this?

```
Hr | M         | Tu   | W    | Th  | F    | Sa | Su
...
8  | Tom       |      |      |     |      |    | 
9  | Tom, Dick | Dick | Dick | Dick| Dick |    | 
...
```

A view of each hour of each day and who is scheduled during that time.

Comment: I can't think of a way without having a 'fixed' hour table (numbers 1-24 or 0-23) to join against.

Comment: @Wrikken fixed hour table granted.  Whats the way?

Comment: [added the example with an hours table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123850/how-to-make-a-mysql-view-for-schedules-of-multiple-people/4126021#4126021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `hours` table (1 integer column `hour`, values 0-23):

```
SELECT
   hour,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(day='Monday'    OR day='Weekdays',name,null) SEPARATOR ','),
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(day='Tuesday'   OR day='Weekdays',name,null) SEPARATOR ','),
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(day='Wednesday' OR day='Weekdays',name,null) SEPARATOR ','),
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(day='Thursday'  OR day='Weekdays',name,null) SEPARATOR ','),
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(day='Friday'    OR day='Weekdays',name,null) SEPARATOR ','),
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(day='Saturday'  OR day='Weekend', name,null) SEPARATOR ','),
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(day='Sunday'    OR day='Weekend', name,null) SEPARATOR ',')
FROM hours 
LEFT JOIN schedule
ON start_hour <= hour AND end_hour > hour OR end_hour = 0
GROUP BY hour;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this query.
It would give you how many guys could start to work at start_hour

start_hour, monday, tuesday
8          2        3

```
SELECT start_hour, SUM(CASE DAY='Moday' THEN 1 END),
        SUM(CASE DAY='Tuesday' THEN 1 END),
        SUM(CASE DAY='Wednesday' THEN 1 END),
 FROM schedule,
 (
 SELECT 'Monday' dayname FROM dual
 UNION
 SELECT 'Tuesday' dayname FROM dual
 UNION
 SELECT 'Wednesday' dayname FROM dual) days,
 WHERE  days.dayname=schedule.dayname
 GROUP BY start_hour
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT start_hour, 
        GROUP_CONCAT( (CASE DAY='Moday' THEN null ELSE Name  END),
        GROUP_CONCAT( (CASE DAY='Tuesday' THEN null ELSE Name  END),
        GROUP_CONCAT( (CASE DAY='Wednesday' THEN null ELSE Name  END),
 FROM schedule,
 (
 SELECT 'Monday' dayname FROM dual
 UNION
 SELECT 'Tuesday' dayname FROM dual
 UNION
 SELECT 'Wednesday' dayname FROM dual) days,
 WHERE  days.dayname=schedule.dayname
 GROUP BY start_hour
```